# How do I get notifications for specific folders?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, notifications, rules

I know that it's possible to make a rule so that you get a notification for *all* folders rather than just the inbox; however, I have rules that direct certain types of emails towards folders because I don't want them to be deleted, but I also don't want them in my inbox.

Similarly, I have rules that direct emails towards folders because they're extra important, and I want them separate from the general stuff that goes to the inbox.

How can I make a rule such that I get notifications for emails that go to my inbox and other specified folders, such as my "important" folder, but still not get notifications for other folders I haven't specified, i.e. my "unimportant" folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I have had this need before and solved it with an additional option within the rule that moves the emails. This gives an alert only when that email is moved to that folder, not for all folders.

[image]

Within the rule, select "display a specific message in the New Items Alert window". Then you can customize the message in the next step. For instance, you can have an alert window that reads **"You have a new important message!"**.